# How to use Android OS VirtualBox as device in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I found this tutorial on how to run Android OS here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/install-android-os-on-pc-with.html

Has anyone tried to use the set-up as a replacement for the emulator? If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used the guide you link to, but instead downloaded an eeepc image from the [Android x86 Project](http://www.android-x86.org). The steps I followed are:

- Install Android to a virtual PC - I used a 64bit virtual machine, enabled all the hardware virtualisation, and used the PCnet-FAST III virtual network adapter in bridged mode - see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HgUD.png)
- Disable host mouse pointer integration - this will allow Android to display it's own mouse pointer so you know where you're clicking.
- You need to work out what IP address the VM has, so that you can connect with `adb connect <YOUR_VIRTUALBOX_IP>`. I do this by logging into my router and identifying the IP of the device that shares the port with my laptop, since that's the Android VM using bridged networking. See image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yfgp.png).

You are supposed to be able to use VBoxManage commands to identify the IP of the guest, but I've never gotten those working, so the router method is the only one I have that works.

Performance is pretty good - much quicker than running hte ARM emulator, though of course, you can only run Android versions that have been compiled for x86.

[image]
[image]

Comment: rivierakid is right, this is great as long as your app doesn't need the google apis

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's true, though I think liveandroid is the same, if I've read it correctly. android-x86 does however have the advantage that it is more actively developed than liveandroid (the latest liveandroid release I can see is from 2009).

Answer (score 2):

> You are supposed to be able to use VBoxManage commands to identify the IP of the guest, but I've never gotten those working, so the router method is the only one I have that works.

Hit Alt + F1. when the root@android prompt comes up, type netcfg and press enter.  That will show you the IP address.  Hit Alt + F7 to get back to the GUI.

Comment: How/where do you make the root@android prompt come up?