# Android High Density Emulator prob

Tags: android, android-emulator, highdpi

In my PC, I can create any medium density emulator(e.g. 1280x768) and run it properly. But when I am trying to run any emulator of high density or extra high density emulator, it is showing black screen only, it is not loading anything and I cannot run any app there, if I try to run any app, it is giving "Error type 2". What is problem? Is it any hardware limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed different add-on like Samsung Galaxy, Motorola Xoom, Xoom2, Xoom2Me etc and create AVD using them, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too face this type of problem earlier. But I have rectified this by using `VirtualBox`.

- [`Install virtual box`](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-and-run-android-4.0-on-mac-windows-pc-or-linux-tutorial/)
- check this for [`how to use virtual box as android emulator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622973/how-to-use-android-os-virtualbox-as-device-in-eclipse)